# Is it possible to get JAVA SDK for wit.ai?

Tags: java, sdk, swagger, wit.ai

I have explored wit.ai github repositories. They do not seem to have official Java SDK for wit.ai. Whereas, they do support other platforms like: nodejs.

Does anyone know an alternative to actually get JAVA SDK for wit.ai?

I tried with sdks.io, but the issue is that the SDK generated, points to mashape url and not directly to wit.ai http url.

I also checked out and found that there are utilities like: restlet studio and other sdk generators which takes swagger document as input and outputs a SDK.

But, I was not able to retrieve the swagger document of wit.ai.

(I was able to retrieve swagger document of marvel comics, but it does not fit to my current usecase)

Any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

This SDK is community-maintained and likely broken. Please use the HTTP API or the Node.js/Python/Ruby SDKs for non-experimental needs (https://wit.ai/docs). We gladly accept pull requests

The SDK can capture intents and entities:

```
from the microphone of the device
from a text (using a Java String)
from an audio stream (using a Java java.io.InputStream)
```